# Find the sum of real roots of a biquadratic equation

Tags: polynomials

Given the following biquadratic equation:
$$x^4-3x^3-2x^2-3x+1=0$$
Find the sum of its real roots.
Let $$f(x)=x^4-3x^3-2x^2-3x+1$$

By observing the behaviour of $f^{'}(x)$, I was able to deduce that the equation has only two real roots, both of then being positive.

Also, using a graphing calculator, the sum is found to be approximately $4$. The answer ia 4.

By Vieta's theorem the sum of roots comes out to be 3. So the sum of the non real roots must be -1.

One potentially useful representation of the equation(I have no idea how it is actually useful) was
$$(x^2-1)^2=3(x^2+1)$$, which clearly shows x cannot be negative, if it is to be a solution.

How do I proceed, without referring to the results found by the graphing calculator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have
$$x^4-3x^3-2x^2-3x+1=(x^2-4x+1)(x^2+x+1)$$
with
$$x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac 12\right)^2+\frac 34\gt 0.$$

Comment: Thanks, the hint was more than enough!

Comment: @Shubham: You are welcome. BTW, is there any reason not to accept any answer in the following question?: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886993/finding-the-range-of-values-of-frac-sqrt1x2-1x

Comment: No specific reason, it's just difficult to decide which one is the best. I upvoted all of them!

Comment: @Shubham: Fine. I just ask:)